# Как отправить данные без перезагрузки страницы и использования action в form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Не получается отправить данные формы на почту, если у меня в html в поле form не прописано action="mail.php". Если прописано, форма отправляется, но и страница переходит на новую пустую страницу. Вместо этого, мне просто необходимо чтобы отправилась форма и появилось окошко на прежней страницы что данные отправлены.
Прилагаю код.

```
<form class="message__form" method="post">
    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Site Name">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="......@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Form Subject">
        <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
    <p>
      <label class="visually-hidden" for="name">Ваше имя</label>
      <input class="name" id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label class="visually-hidden" for="phone">Ваше телефон</label>
      <input class="phone" id="phone" type="text" name="phone" value="" placeholder="Ваше телефон" required>
    </p>
    <button class="button-send button" type="submit" name="button">Отправить</button>
```

```
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
var th = $(this);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./mail.php", //Change
  data: th.serialize()
}).done(function() {
  alert("Thank you!");
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Done Functions
    th.trigger("reset");
  }, 1000);
});
return false;
```

});

> ```
>     <?php
> $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
> //Script Foreach
> $c = true;
> if ( $method === 'POST' ) {
>   $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
>   $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
>   $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);
>   foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
>     if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
>       $message .= "
>       " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
>         <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
>         <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
>       </tr>
>       ";
>     }
>   }
> } else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {
>   $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
>   $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
>   $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);
>   foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
>     if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
>       $message .= "
>       " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
>         <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
>         <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
>       </tr>
>       ";
>     }
>   }
> }
> $message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";
> function adopt($text) {
>   return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
> }
> $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
> 'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
> 'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;
> mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
> ?>
> ```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.querySelector('.button-send');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Отменяем стандартное событие.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Делаем, что нужно.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });
```